# How to drop multiple columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to drop 200 columns in my table in PostgreSQL. I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
DROP COLUMN col1, col2
```

But I get an error like this:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "col2"

Comment: I'd be concerned if I had 200 columns in a table, let alone want to drop them. If this is more than a one-off exceptional event take a step back and look at your design.

Comment: This question is valid and useful, but the fact that it starts from the premise *"I want to drop 200 columns"* is entertainingly wild. In case you're someone new to SQL arriving at this question and wondering to yourself "wait, is *having*, let alone *dropping*, 200 columns in a table a typical practice?", please be assured the answer is "no"!

Answer (score 300, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html), you can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP COLUMN col1, DROP COLUMN col2;
```

(You may need to wrap some of your column names in `"` quotes if they happen to be keywords.)

Comment: Does not work for me. I get: `ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near ","`

Comment: You can even leave out 'COLUMN' and use `ALTER TABLE table DROP col1, DROP col2;`

Answer (score -1):

Thanks [long](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1453425/long) & [Ondrej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1035634/ondrej-burkert) - below commands worked for me,

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name_1,DROP COLUMN column_name_2,DROP COLUMN column_name_3; 

ALTER TABLE table_name DROP column_name_1,DROP column_name_2,DROP column_name_3;
```

Answer (score -5):

This worked for me:

```
alter table your_table_name drop column your_column_name;
```

Comment: They asked for multiple columns, not one. However, you could run this multiple times for each column.